# Android Packager: [main] java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: classes.dex

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm building an Android application in IntelliJ IDEA . I am using the most recent Android SDK tools as of 10/22/2013 which goes up to API level 18 for the recently released Android 4.3. My build target is Android 4.3 and my Java SDK is 1.7.

When I attempt to build my application, the build fails with the following message:

Android Packager: [main] java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: classes.dex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem as yours just now.Actually,you don't have to reinstall IDE,just rebuild the project.It works here.

Comment: Yeah, I did a manual removal of a files of the compile output directory. This directory had an old classes.dex. The new android packager does not create this file anymore in this location.

Comment: @j4nbur53 How do you remove files from the compile output directory

Answer (score 4):

- Have you tried clean project ?
- Manually go to 'bin' directory and remove everything, and try to build your project now.
- Is this project depends on any library project ?, If so try to clean and build that project.

Comment: Thank you for the support. I fixed it up by Reinstalling the Android Studio.