# Android error in building application. java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/view/ActionMode$Callback.class

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-support-design, android-multidex

On running my application in android studio, i am getting following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/view/ActionMode$Callback.class

here is sdk version and build tools

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
```

here is my gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.2.1'
compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
compile project(':Cropper')
compile project(':volley')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.43.jar')
compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.43.jar')
compile files('libs/acra-4.6.1.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

}

moreover i am using volley api and a cropper library. Both libs don't have any dependency. I don't know where i am using duplicate library.

Also before upgrading design library(support:design), i was using following dependency:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.0.0'
compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
compile project(':Cropper')
compile project(':volley')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.43.jar')
compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.43.jar')
compile files('libs/acra-4.6.1.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

}

And it was working properly but after doing changes these dependency start throwing same error. I am unable to understand the problem.

Please help to sort out this problem as i stucked here completely.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `duplicate entry` . Comment each .and debug .same type causes this

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya yea bug is like but there is no duplicate dependency.. what is the solution??

Answer (score 0):

So after spending my half day i concluded to that there is nothing you need to do with this error... Just rebuild your project or clean and the problem of duplicates will resolve. Thanks to this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513503/android-packager-main-java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-classes-de)

So according to me when you update your library like support-design or v7 you should rebuild your project as it may be that any updation have same name of file which is already in libraries which have been already compiled which conflicts with the new ones. So always remember to rebuild your project after updation of any library.

Thanks